# how to load a big webpage into a string

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm a novice with Java and Android, but not to programming and HTTP. This HTTP GET method, mostly copied from other examples using the Apache HTTP classes, only retrieves the first few K of a large webpage. I checked that the webpage does not have lines longer than 8192 bytes (is that possible?), but out of webpages around 40K I get back maybe 6K, maybe 20K. The number of bytes read does not seem to have a simple realtionship with the total webpage size, or the webpage modulus 8192, or with the webpage content.

Any ideas folks?

Thanks!

```
public static String myHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI(url));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sbuffer.append(line + "\n");
    }
    in.close();

    String result = sbuffer.toString();
    return result; 
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know where you've got that 8192 number from, but it most likely has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: 8192 is the buffer size for BufferedReader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write you own HttpEntity-to-String code, try [EntityUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) instead:

```
// this uses the charset the server encoded the entity in
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: If you want to see how `EntityUtils.toString()` does it, check out its [source code](http://google.com/codesearch#CskViEIa27Y/src/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java&q=org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils&type=cs&l=107) -- there's actually no need to do line-based reading if you're interested in the whole string.

Comment: "no need to do line-based reading" - that has a certain appeal! In truth, I am extracting little bits from a large page, had also considered doing this "on the fly" if the web page proved to be emarassingly long.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the problem is with pages from a certain website starting Goo... I'm not having this problem with large pages from other sites. So the code is probably OK.